# I am gettiing an error expected new line while compiling SASS

Tags: css, sass

I m having issues where my SASS won't just compile and its showing me the same error: Expected NewLine

```
#topper, h3 {    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.list-group{
    .active{
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight:bold
    }
}
```

Error Shown. Tried Everything even deleting and putting left braces in new line

```
  ╷
1 │ #topper, h3 {
  │             ^
  ╵
  home.sass 1:13  root stylesheet
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to compile your styles as SASS when you actually mean SCSS.

Comment: Thank you It should be scss.

Comment: I got this too when accidentally using `sass` instead of `scss` as the `--style=` option during project generation.

Comment: The above syntax is _scss_ and not _sass_... sass does not have the { and thus in sass it expects  a newline where the { is

Answer (score 19):

According to [Sass-lang.com](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax) and the comment of @Nit you have chosen wrong compile options.

this is SCSS

```
@mixin button-base() {
  @include typography(button);
  @include ripple-surface;
  @include ripple-radius-bounded;

  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  height: $button-height;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;

  &:hover { cursor: pointer; }

  &:disabled {
    color: $mdc-button-disabled-ink-color;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Same in SASS

```
@mixin button-base()
  @include typography(button)
  @include ripple-surface
  @include ripple-radius-bounded

  display: inline-flex
  position: relative
  height: $button-height
  border: none
  vertical-align: middle

  &:hover
    cursor: pointer

  &:disabled
    color: $mdc-button-disabled-ink-color
    cursor: default
    pointer-events: none
```

Comment: What compile options should I have chosen? If it doesn't matter what file format I choose, be it Sass or SCSS, and all I need to do is change a compile option, then what is the option I need to provide on the commandline to compile SCSS to CSS using `sass` dart compiler?

Comment: scss and sass have not the same syntax. I was elaborating a comment on question and added examples for further understanding. I'm not familiar with the dart compiler and therefore can't give you an answer sorry...

Comment: sass abandoned the sass compiler that was built with ruby, and now they build the sass cli with dart. FYI

Comment: This helped realize I was using the wrong compiler

Answer (score 9):

You just need to rename yours file extension from *.sass to *.scss to compile your file by SCSS compile option.

I've used sass dart.

sass \source\style1.scss  \result\style1.css

Comment: I am the eighth who just did that