# Why does the Sass compiler return an error with "root stylesheet"

Tags: css, sass

If I have a .sass file with this content

```
h1 {}
```

and I run `sass a.sass` I get the output: "root stylesheet"

```
app $ sass app.component.sass 
Error: Expected newline.
  ╷
1 │ h1 {}
  │    ^
  ╵
  a.sass 1:4  root stylesheet
```

I have been looking at the documentation, but I can't understand why a valid CSS file can't be compiled using the `sass` dart CLI.

My goal is to write some CSS sometimes, but I want to use Sass sometimes, too. Am I forced to use SCSS because every CSS file is a valid SCSS file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858150/i-am-gettiing-an-error-expected-new-line-while-compiling-sass

Comment: @spaceholder I added a comment to the community wiki answer. I don't see how this question is being answered. The answer that is shown only mentions that "you passed the wrong options" but I don't see any correct option being pointed out. I want to know explicitly if I have to format my files in Sass indented syntax in order to use the `sass` compiler. It's not clear to me if I can write SCSS and compile to CSS using `sass` -- this answer seems to point to a missing command line option but then doesn't tell me what it is.